# ApplicationUser and ApplicationRole navigation properties in Identity 2.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity-2

in Identity 2.0.0 we have Roles navigation property in ApplicationUser with type IdentityUserRoles
and we have Users navigation property in IdentityRole with same type IdentityUserRoles

here it is

```cs
namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
{
    // Summary:
    //     EntityType that represents a user belonging to a role
    //
    // Type parameters:
    //   TKey:
    public class IdentityUserRole<TKey>
    {
        public IdentityUserRole();

        // Summary:
        //     RoleId for the role
        public virtual TKey RoleId { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     UserId for the user that is in the role
        public virtual TKey UserId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

so, when i iterate through context.Users i can get only RoleId

is there a way to make standart many-to-many mapping between ApplicationUser and ApplicationRole ?

i want to be able doing something like this

```cs
foreach (var user in ApplicationDbContextInstance.Users)
{
    List<ApplicationRole> UserRoles = user.Roles.ToList();
    /*
    some logic ... 
    */ 
}
```

**UPDATE:**

after some work on this question i have found a solution for my case.
maybe its not so elegant as it can be, but in my case i have to extend IdentityUserRole with additional navigation properties

i have extended IdentityUserRole to ApplicationUserRole and make appropriate changes in all solution.
here is my new IdentityUserRole:

```cs
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GeoSectorForUser> GeoSectors { get; set; }
}
```

and now i can get all users in certain role like this:

```cs
foreach(ApplicationRole role in db.Roles){
    List<ApplicationUser> users = role.Users.Select(s => s.User).ToList();
}
```

in my case AplicationUserRole is needed for storing additional navigation properties so that solution is worked for me.
but i still wondering how to create clean many-to-many relation between IdentityUser and IdentityRole

Comment: `IdentityUserRole` is the intermediate object that is already providing the many-to-many relationship. so `IdentityUser` <-> `IdentityUserRole` <-> `IdentityRole'

Comment: Your update doesn't work for me. I get Exceptions when trying to create a new Migration.

Answer (score 2):

`IdentityUser.Roles()` gives you a collection of `IdentityUserRole` objects which contain only `RoleId` and `UserId` properties. To get a collection of the `Role` objects for a user, you should use the `RoleManager` class (typing this off the top of my head so may not work 100%):

```
var roleManager = new RoleManager();

foreach (var user in ApplicationDbContextInstance.Users)
{
    List<IdentityUserRole> UserRoles = user.Roles.ToList();

    foreach(var userRole in UserRoles)
    {
        var role = roleManager.FindbyId(userRole.RoleId);
    }

}
```

Comment: yes. that is how i have to use it. but my question is about posibility of standart many-to-many mapping. anyway, thank you for answer